# Definition of partitiom

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Considering a partition $P$ on a set:

If we consider $P$ the partition such that $\lnot R(x,y) \iff x,y$ are in a different cell.

Is this equivalent to saying that $P$ is the partition such that $R(x,y) \iff x,y$ are in the same cell of P?

Comment: Is that the definition of $R(x,y)$?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are asking, but $\neg R$ is not an equivalence relation. If $R$ is the relation $xRy$ if $x,y$ belong to the same part in the partition $P$, then yes, $\neg R(x,y)$  would mean $x,y$ are in different parts, obviously.

Comment: I was asking if it was OK to define a partition induced by an eq. Relation as the sets of all cells such that two elements are in a different cell iff they do not share the eq. Relation in question

Comment: In order to formalize this: partition such that ¬R(x,y) iff x,y are in a different cell, would be be sufficient to write 
    ¬R(x,y) iff $\lnot$ $\exists$ $X$ such that x,y$\in$X